# Unable to locate package libX11-dev

Tags: installation, libraries

I was trying to build HTK using Ubuntu 11.04.

These are the commands I used:

```
sudo ./configure 
make all
```

I immediately get the error:

```
X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
```

So when I try to install `libX11-dev` by using:

```
sudo apt-get install libX11-dev
```

I got the following error:

```
Unable to locate package libX11-dev
```

I'd appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 11):

That's because the file is named `libx11-dev`

synaptic would be a good thing to have installed & to use for such activities

Comment: Is this true for present versions of OS (e.g. Ubuntu 16.04 or 17.04)?

Comment: the name remains the same

Comment: For anyone who didn't see it right away, the difference is in the case (all lowercase letters.) And if this doesn't help, [this thread might](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178508/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lx11-error-when-installing-htk/1084878#1084878).